# boost asio async_read_some timeout

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I use this code using `async_read_some` with timeout

```
        readdata=0;
        port_->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(vector),
                boost::bind(readCallback));


        //init async timer
        boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io);
        timer.async_wait(boost::bind(timeoutHandler));
        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

        io.reset();
        do {
            io.run_one();
        }
        while (readdata==0);
```

here are my callbacks

```
void readCallback()
{
    std::cout << "READ CALLBACK: "<<x<<std::endl;
    readdata=1;
    return;
}
void timeoutHandler()
{
   std::cout << "TIMEOUT CALLBACK: "<<x<<std::endl;
   readdata=1;
}
```

my Problem is that timeoutHandler is is executed instantly and not after 5 seconds

Comment: It has been a while since I used asio but what happens when you remove the `io.reset()`? It might cause the `async_wait` to reset

Comment: Like @SteveVanOpstal said, you should remove that `io.reset()`. You're adding tasks to the async event handler (io_service), and then resetting it immediately before you run the service that will execute the events you added (which you do with `run_one()`). I recommend that you read and learn more about `io_service` and how it works.

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but with same result, `timeoutHandler()` is called instantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple mistake. You should be doing `expires_from_now` before calling `async_wait`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main() {
  asio::io_service io_s;
  asio::deadline_timer timer(io_s);
  timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  timer.async_wait([](auto err_c) { std::cout << "After 5 seconds" << std::endl; } );

  io_s.reset();

  io_s.run();

  return 0;
}
```